# How to apply Chisq.test on levels of different categorical variables?

Tags: r, statistics, sapply, chi-squared

I want to perform `chisq.test()` on each level of the categorical variable.

Currently, I have managed to do it on each categorical variable using below code.

```
# Random generation of values for categorical data
set.seed(12)
x <- data.frame(col1 = sample( LETTERS[1:4], 100, replace=TRUE ), 
                col2 = sample( LETTERS[3:6], 100, replace=TRUE ),
                col3 = sample( LETTERS[2:5], 100, replace=TRUE ),
                out = sample(c(1,2),100, replace=TRUE))

# performing chisq.test
pval <- as.data.frame(sapply(c(1:3),function(i)chisq.test(x[,i],x[,'out'])$p.value ))

#output
    p.value
1 0.33019256
2 0.08523487
3 0.79403367
```

I am interested to compare the levels at different outcomes.

```
# for col1 levels different outcomes
table(x$col1,x$out)

#output
     1  2
  A  8 12
  B 18 10
  C 12 11
  D 18 11
```

For example, to compare level B in `col1` for different outcomes 1,2 in `out`.

I would like to know how can this be extended(or in another smart way) to each level of a categorical variable ?

```
# Expected output
       p.value

col1.A  *****
col1.B  *****
col1.C  *****
.
.
.
col3.E  *****
```

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: What do you mean? How are you proposing to do a `chisq.test` on only one level of a factor?

Comment: @thelatemail I want to compare each level for different outcomes. I have tried to give an example, does that make sense ?

Comment: @NickK Even I was wondering on how to approach this after one of my colleague has aproached me with a question from [this paper](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/1471-0528.12195/epdf). In table1, they have compared different education levels on the disease. Please correct me if my understanding and the question asked here is not related.

Comment: For each of the categories they've assessed, for each one they've constructed a 2x2 contingency table e.g. tertiary education vs. no tertiary education in rows and pre-eclampsia vs. no pre-eclampsia in columns. This is different to what you asked in your question. Your categories are mutually exclusive (for column 1, you can't be A+B), whereas theirs are overlapping (you can have tertiary education and <12 years schooling at least in their dataset, though that seems unusual to me).

Comment: @NickK Thanks for the explanation, I have now understood that example is not relevant to my question. The overlapping education parameters are ambiguous to me unlike Smoking status categorical variable.

Comment: I'm still not sure that I've given you what you want though. I suspect you may want to either be doing A vs non A, B vs non B, etc. It would be easier if you gave more context. For smoking status, you might want to do current vs non-current and ever vs never.

Comment: @NickK I have got the input from your explanation. I have advised my colleague to carry the `chi.sq` on the Smoking status which has three levels and follow the same for other categorical variables having n*2 contingency table(n>1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you would do it if you wanted to do a Chi-squared test for given probabilities (with `p = rep(0.5, 2)`).

I've broken this down to make it easier to understand:

```
getP <- function(lev, x, i) {
  tab <- table(x$out[x[, i] == lev])
  chisq.test(tab)$p.value
}
pvalList <- lapply(1:3, function(i) {
  df <- data.frame(Column = i, Category = levels(x[, i]))
  df$p.value <- sapply(df$Category, getP, x, i)
  df
})
pval <- do.call("rbind", pvalList) # Convert to single data frame
```

Alternatively, if what you want is actually A vs not A, B vs not B, etc., you could substitute the definition of `getP` with:

```
getP <- function(lev, x, i) {
  tab <- table(x$out, x[, i] == lev)
  chisq.test(tab)$p.value
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I am a R beginner. Though I didn't understand the solution you have provided now,  hope I will understand in next few minutes.